# how to turn big dictionary list into a text

Tags: python, dictionary

so i have got these big lists of dictionaries like :

```
d = [{"country": "Argentina", "country_code": "AR", "slots": 207},
 {"country": "Australia", "country_code": "AU", "slots": 2471},
 {"country": "Austria", "country_code": "AT", "slots": 179}, 
 {"country": "Bahrain", "country_code": "BH", "slots": 7}, 
 {"country": "Bangladesh", "country_code": "BD", "slots": 5}, 
 {"country": "Belarus", "country_code": "BY", "slots": 4}, 
 {"country": "Belgium", "country_code": "BE", "slots": 58}, 
 {"country": "Bolivia", "country_code": "BO", "slots": 3}, 
 {"country": "Bosniaand Herzegovina", "country_code": "BA", "slots": 4}, 
 {"country": "Brazil", "country_code": "BR", "slots": 460}, 
 {"country": "Brunei", "country_code": "BN", "slots": 8}, 
 {"country": "Bulgaria", "country_code": "BG", "slots": 42}, 
 {"country": "Canada", "country_code": "CA", "slots": 639}, 
 {"country": "Chile", "country_code": "CL", "slots": 101}, 
 {"country": "Colombia", "country_code": "CO", "slots": 31}, 
 {"country": "Costa Rica", "country_code": "CR", "slots": 24}, 
 {"country": "Cyprus", "country_code": "CY", "slots": 11},
 {"country": "Czechia", "country_code": "CZ", "slots": 45}, 
 {"country": "Denmark", "country_code": "DK", "slots": 78},
 {"country": "Dominican Republic", "country_code": "DO", "slots": 15}, 
 {"country": "Ecuador", "country_code": "EC", "slots": 17}, 
 {"country": "El Salvador", "country_code": "SV", "slots": 20}, 
 {"country": "Estonia", "country_code": "EE", "slots": 5}, 
 {"country": "Finland", "country_code": "FI", "slots": 31}, 
 {"country": "France", "country_code": "FR", "slots": 1203}, 
 {"country": "Germany", "country_code": "DE", "slots": 1149}, 
 {"country": "Ghana", "country_code": "GH", "slots": 9}, 
 {"country": "Greece", "country_code": "GR", "slots": 16}, 
 {"country": "Guatemala", "country_code": "GT", "slots": 28}, 
 {"country": "Honduras", "country_code": "HN", "slots": 15}, 
 {"country": "Hungary", "country_code": "HU", "slots": 37}, 
 {"country": "Iceland", "country_code": "IS", "slots": 10}, 
 {"country": "India", "country_code": "IN", "slots": 11}, 
 {"country": "Indonesia", "country_code": "ID", "slots": 116}, 
 {"country": "Ireland", "country_code": "IE", "slots": 202}, 
 {"country": "Israel", "country_code": "IL", "slots": 35}, 
 {"country": "Italy", "country_code": "IT", "slots": 236}, 
 {"country": "Jordan", "country_code": "JO", "slots": 5}, 
 {"country": "Kuwait", "country_code": "KW", "slots": 9}, 
 {"country": "Liechtenstein", "country_code": "LI", "slots": 3}, 
 {"country": "Lithuania", "country_code": "LT", "slots": 11}, 
 {"country": "Luxembourg", "country_code": "LU", "slots": 16}, 
 {"country": "Malawi", "country_code": "MW", "slots": 4}, 
 {"country": "Malaysia", "country_code": "MY", "slots": 558}, 
 {"country": "Mexico", "country_code": "MX", "slots": 197}, 
 {"country": "Morocco", "country_code": "MA", "slots": 8}, 
 {"country": "Namibia", "country_code": "NA", "slots": 4}, 
 {"country": "Netherlands", "country_code": "NL", "slots": 101}, 
 {"country": "New Zealand", "country_code": "NZ", "slots": 90}, 
 {"country": "Nicaragua", "country_code": "NI", "slots": 5}, 
 {"country": "Nigeria", "country_code": "NG", "slots": 13}, 
 {"country": "Norway", "country_code": "NO", "slots": 293}, 
 {"country": "Pakistan", "country_code": "PK", "slots": 19}, 
 {"country": "Panama", "country_code": "PA", "slots": 24}, 
 {"country": "Paraguay", "country_code": "PY", "slots": 14}, 
 {"country": "Peru", "country_code": "PE", "slots": 27}, 
 {"country": "Philippines", "country_code": "PH", "slots": 129}, 
 {"country": "Poland", "country_code": "PL", "slots": 184}, 
 {"country": "Portugal", "country_code": "PT", "slots": 23}, 
 {"country": "Romania", "country_code": "RO", "slots": 34}, 
 {"country": "Saudi Arabia", "country_code": "SA", "slots": 6}, 
 {"country": "Senegal", "country_code": "SN", "slots": 6}, 
 {"country": "Serbia", "country_code": "RS", "slots": 5}, 
 {"country": "Singapore", "country_code": "SG", "slots": 274}]
```

And I want to output them into

```
Country     |  Country Code  |  Slot
Argentina  |       AR           |  5
seterusnya |     example        |  5
seterusnya |     example        |  6
seterusnya |     example        |  7
seterusnya |     example        |  8
```

does anyone have any ideas? thanks beforehand

Comment: Your output is not a known Python data strucure. What is it? A list of strings representing rows? A file? A multi line string? Console output? Do the pipes have to be aligned? PLs specify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Mark's answer, one elegant way to do it, if you just want to print it in a nice table, is to use the `pandas` library. It should first be pip installed. Then, you can simply do

```py
import pandas as pd

dct = [
    {"country": "Argentina", "country_code": "AR", "slots": 207},
    {"country": "Australia", "country_code": "AU", "slots": 2471},
    ...
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df.columns = ["Country", "Country Code", "Slot"]
print(df)

# Maybe you want to sort by the slots to get the countries 
# with the highest slots at the top
df = df.sort_values(by="Slot", ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

# Export to CSV if you want - it can then be accessed easily later
df.to_csv("countries.csv", index=False, sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to turn it into a dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

To print in text format, you can use `pd.to_string()`:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```